# The name of fields where the characteristic equals the order of the field

Tags: abstract-algebra

So the finite fields are precisely the fields of order $p^k$. These have characteristic $p$.

Do fields of prime order (ie. $\mathbb{F}_2$, $\mathbb{F}_3$, $\mathbb{F}_5$, ...) have a special name (as opposed to, say, $\mathbb{F}_4$, $\mathbb{F}_9$, $\mathbb{F}_{25}$, ...)? Do they have "nicer" properties?

Comment: I think they are called prime fields

Comment: You can find more about it on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elaborating on Edouard's comment: given any field $F$, there is a *least* subfield $F_0$ of $F$ - namely, the subfield generated by $0$ and $1$. $F_0$ is called the *prime subfield* of $F$, and is always isomorphic to either $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime if $F$ has characteristic $p$, or $\mathbb{Q}$ if $F$ has characteristic $0$ (e.g. $F=\mathbb{R}$).

The only nice property I can think of is that prime fields, by definition, have no proper subfields (remember that $\{0\}$ isn't a field - the [field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element), *isn't*). Off the top of my head, I can't think of anything this immediately buys you, though.